# ActiveRecord, pgsql: query multiple records by multiple index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my `Users` table, a user is defined by a unique multiple-index of the pair `account_id`, and `location_id`.
When I got a request to get data for a specific pair of account/location I can easily retrieve data for this one pair:

```
account_location_hash = { account_id: 2, location_id: 3 }
user = User.find_by(account_location_hash)
```

However, When I need to find multiple users, having an array of hashes (hundreds of pairs), there is no simple way to get the entities I need, although I've got the expected list of indexes of those entities.
I tried using:

```
pairs_array = [{ account_id: 2, location_id: 3 },{ account_id: 1, location_id: 4 }]
user = User.where(pairs_array)
```

but this doesn't work.

I can find more complex solutions, like construct a query of AND's and OR's, or creating a temporary table of the pairs I got and JOIN the tables, but none of them feels right.
Am I missing a simpler approach?

Comment: I recently had a situation where I wanted to query by a long list of IDs. I ended up creating a temporary table, which allowed me to do use some joins instead of passing hundreds of IDs. It's not a direct answer to your question, but it may be worth considering.

Comment: An `OR` is required in this case as `AND` will result in 0 records. How simple this is to solve depends on what rails version you are using. e.g. in rails 5 `@users = User.scoped; pairs_array.each {|pair| @users = @users.or(User.where(pair))}` should suffice

Comment: @engineersmnky, looks simple enough. Though scoped is deprecated in rails 4 but this seems to work:  `@users = User.none; pairs_array.each {|pair| @users = @users.or(User.where(pair))}`

Comment: @isaac-fisher fair enough. `User.all` would also be sufficient given the additional scoping that is occurring in the loop

Comment: @engineersmnky `User.all` will not do because no matter how much `.or` we will add it'll just leave it with all the elements (as in true OR false OR false...). Thanks for the answer, it's really helpful! (and thanks god I'm using rails 5 and don't need Arel)

Comment: @isaac-fisher glad it works for you. `all` should be fine too because it just returns a scope (based on the current scope or `default_scope`) and thus can be filtered. [`ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named#all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all)

Comment: @engineersmnky could not make it work with `.all`. This is the best I got so far:
`pairs_array.reduce(User.none) { |query, pair| query.or(User.where(pair)) }`

Answer (score 0):

This is the least complex solution I found so far (used @engineersmnky comment, rails 5):

```
pairs_array.reduce(User.none) {|users, pair| users.or(User.where(pair))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
pairs_array = [{ account_id: 2, location_id: 3 },{ account_id: 1, location_id: 4 }]

account_ids = []
location_ids = []
pairs_array.each do |h|
  account_ids << h[:account_id]
  location_ids << h[:location_id]
end

User.where('account_id IN (?) AND location_id IN (?)', account_ids, location_ids).load
```

Comment: no, because you will also get users with `account_id: 2, location_id: 4` which isn't in the request